# Problems with upgrade laravel 4.2 to 5.0

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-4

i got this method on my routes.php:

```
Route::resource('maintenance/templates', 'TemplateController', ['names' => createRouteNames('fleet.maintenance.templates')]);
```

But, i understand, this method break in laravel 5 so, How can i upgrade this method? I understand i need use `Route::group(` but, i don't know how.

This is one of the tries i did, but, it didn't work:

```
Route::group(['maintenance/templates' => 'TemplateController'], function(){

    Route::resource('template/config', 'ConfigController',[
        'only' => ['store', 'update', 'destroy'],
        'names' => createRouteNames('fleet.template.config'),
    ]);

    Route::controller('template', 'TemplateController', [
        'getTemplates' => 'api.template',
        'postService' => 'api.template.service',
    ]);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `group` for the `resource` function. You can achieve it like this:

```
Route::resource('maintenance/templates', 'TemplateController', [
    'only' => [
        'store', 'update', 'destroy'
    ],
    'names' => [
        'store' => 'maintenance/templates.store',
        'update' => 'maintenance/templates.update',
        'destroy' => 'maintenance/templates.destroy',
    ]
]);
```

Or you can pass a callable that will return an associative array like the example above:

```
Route::resource('maintenance/templates', 'TemplateController', [
    'only' => [
        'store', 'update', 'destroy'
    ],
    'names' => createRouteNames('fleet.maintenance.templates')
]);
```

Comment: It returns me `Call to a member function only() on null` :(

Comment: @LuisOsuna Oh sorry, I thought you were upgrading to `5.6`. Hmm as for `5.0`, why do you say your function is breaking? Any errors?

Comment: @LuisOsuna Take a look at my update, does this work for you?